# How to make emacs or emacsclient exit with nonzero return code?

Tags: exit

How to exit emacs with nonzero return code?

And how to achieve that also with emacsclient?

Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/295156/how-to-set-the-exit-status-for-emacsclient/542916

Comment: Maybe if you expand your question with what you're trying to achieve, you'll attract some more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `kill-emacs`. From its help:

> kill-emacs is an interactive built-in function in `C source code'.
>   (kill-emacs &optional ARG)
>
> Exit the Emacs job and kill it. If ARG is an integer, return ARG as
>   the exit program code. If ARG is a string, stuff it as keyboard input.
>
> The value of `kill-emacs-hook', if not void, is a list of functions
>   (of no args), all of which are called before Emacs is actually killed.
>
> [back]

Note that `kill-emacs` is *not* the normal exit function bound to `C-x C-c`. That is `save-buffers-kill-emacs`.

Additionally `kill-emacs` called from an `emacsclient` will kill the client *and* the server.

`server-edit`, bound to `C-x C-#` is how you close buffers and the `emacsclient`. From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html):

> But C-x # is the way to tell emacsclient that you are finished.

Maybe if you explore what `server-edit` is doing, (and `server.el` in general) you'll find some clues.

Comment: any killing-the-client-only version?