# How to pass an optional agrument to kill-emacs?

Tags: exit

I would like a way to make emacs to return a non-zero exit code when exiting.

This page https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Emacs.html lists the command

**kill-emacs** *&optional exit-data*

as a mechanism for making emacs return with non-zero return code, stating *"If exit-data is an integer, that is used as the exit status of the Emacs process"*.

How do I add this optional exit-data?

I have tried:

- Interactively using *<kbd>M-x</kbd> kill-emacs* but cannot type a space after that.
- Setting up a binding in my *init.el* using `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-M-c") 'kill-emacs)`, but do not know the syntax well enough to pass an argument.

I see this is related to [How to set the exit status for emacsclient](https://superuser.com/questions/295156/how-to-set-the-exit-status-for-emacsclient/542916) and [How to make emacs or emacsclient exit with nonzero return code?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48726/how-to-make-emacs-or-emacsclient-exit-with-nonzero-return-code) , but I cannot get the answer I want from those questions/answers.

Please can someone explain how to quit emacs with a non-zero return code and/or provide the syntax to setup a keyboard binding.

Comment: I was going to suggest  looking at the doc string of the function with `C-h f kill-emacs RET` which should tell how to pass arguments to the function interactively, but in this case, that is not mentioned, perhaps assuming that this is "common knowledge". I wonder if a bug report on the doc string is warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactively, you can use a prefix argument.

E.g.:

- $ `emacs -Q`
- <kbd>M-7</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `kill-emacs` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- $ `echo $?`
  => `7`

A command to do this, which you could bind to a key sequence, would be:

```el
(defun my-kill-emacs ()
  (interactive)
  "Exit emacs with status 7."
  (kill-emacs 7))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I've accepted the answer. Thanks!